# why every maximum-modulus eigenvalue of A is semisimple?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in  M_n$ be a nonnegative nonzero matrix that has a positive eigenvector.

why every maximum-modulus eigenvalue of A is semisimple?

Comment: You don't have $M_n$ regular or positive? In this case it is the Perron Frobenius theorem

Comment: @TsemoAristide - In the Perron Frobenius theorem if $A>0$ then .....but here is $A\ge0$.